# \TPShowGrid Doesn't Work with Overleaf

Tags: textpos

Is anyone else having this issue?
According to the documentation and the examples, the following MWE should show a grid, but it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\TPShowGrid{4}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: I copy and pasted David's code into a blank file in my Overleaf project and it did not work. This is peculiar.

[image]

Comment: The grid  shows on overleaf using your code https://www.overleaf.com/read/mryzcthmftnj

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. That link does indeed work. I am confused because I copy and paste the code into my current project and it fails. See edit.

Comment: Which version of texlive does your project use?

Comment: check the left sidebar menu that is probably an old project using texlive 2020 or older rather than 2021. Also note that you have 4 errors if asking about an error always show the exact error from the log don't describe the PDF output which is not intended to be usable after any error

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle! I didn't know about switching the version. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need the texlive 2021 version.

Using Overleaf new projects will use texlive 2021 but if you are editing an old project it will keep using the version of texlive that was originally used. You can switch the texlive version in the left hand sidebar menu.

An example Overleaf project (that I may not keep forever)

https://www.overleaf.com/read/mryzcthmftnj